# jquery validate plugin if checkbox is checked textarea cannot be empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I searched SO and there was a similar question but that was with asp, but my code is in pure jquery, not asp.

My use case is following:

I have a html5 form, with various html fields. I'm using jQuery 3.2.1 and the jquery validate plugin to validate the fields. I'm able to validate all the text inputs, drop downs but having a problem w/ textarea which is dependent on a checkbox. If the user enters text into the textarea (called 'description') (minimum 5 characters) but doesn't check one of the 2 checkboxes (with the id 'usa'), I need to display the error message. It has to validate vice-versa as well - ie if user checks one of the two checkboxes (with id 'usa') but doesn't enter any text into the textarea (called 'description'), (minimum 5 characters), then an error message needs to be displayed as well.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" name="paymentInformation"      id="paymentInformation" action="verifyOrder.cfm" method="post" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
     <fieldset class="col-sm-12">

  <!-- Row 1 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="booktype" class="col-6 col-form-label">
        Book Type *
      </label>
      <select class="custom-select col-4" id="booktype" name="booktype">
        <option selected value="">Select book type</option>
        <option value="val1">E-BOOK</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="id2" class="col-6 col-form-label">
        Number
      </label>
      <input type="form-control" placeholder="Number" type="text" id="id2" name="id2" class="col-10">
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /Row 1 -->
  <!-- Row 2 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="firstname" class="col-6 col-form-label">
        First Name *
      </label>
      <input type="form-control" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="col-12" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="id2" class="col-6 col-form-label">
        Book Name
      </label>
      <input type="form-control" placeholder="Book Name" type="text" id="id3" name="id3" class="col-10">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /Row 2 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="lastname" class="col-6 col-form-label">
        Last Name *
      </label>
      <input type="form-control" type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="col-12" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /Row 2 -->
  <label for="description" class="col-10 col-form-label">
    Country description
  </label>
  <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="4" class="form-control txtarea-rounded"></textarea>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="col-sm-6">Countries: </label>
    <br />
    <label class="form-check-label col-10">
      <input class="form-check-input col-10" type="checkbox" name="usa" value="Y" id="usa">USA
      <br />
      <input class="form-check-input col-10" type="checkbox" name="uk" value="Y" id="uk"> UK
    </label>
  </div>

</fieldset>
   </div>
   <div class="hideDiv">
     <input type="submit" name=btnSubmit value="PROCEED TO THE NEXT STEP &#xf054;" class="blueButton">
   </div>
 </form>
```

Following is my javascript:

```
  var authorlist = [{"AUTHOR":"DONNA       EDWARDS","COUNTRY":"USA","REGION":"MIDWEST"},{"AUTHOR":"EMERALD JONES","COUNTRY":"UK","REGION":"EU"},      {"AUTHOR":"SHAKESPEARE","COUNTRY":"UK","REGION":"EU"}];
  function checkName(){
    var nameIsValid = true;
    var nametocheck = $("#id3").val();
    $.each(authorlist, function(index, val){
//console.log(val.AUTHOR);
      if(val.AUTHOR.toUpperCase() == nametocheck.toUpperCase()){
    //console.log(val.AUTHOR);
    nameIsValid = false;
  return false;
}
    });
    return nameIsValid;
    }

  function checkForm() {
var formIsValid = checkName() && $("#paymentInformation").valid();
    if (formIsValid) {
$(".hideDiv").show();
    } else {
$(".hideDiv").hide();
    }
  }

  $("#booktype").on("change", function() {
    checkForm();
  });

  $("#paymentInformation").on("keyup", function() {
    checkForm();
  });

  // add the rule here
  $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg) {
    return arg !== value;
  }, "Value must not equal arg.");

  //add 2nd rule here
  $.validator.addMethod("booknameExists", function(value,element,arg){

  }, "Book name must not pre-exist");

  $.validator.setDefaults({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.parent('.input-group').length || element.prop('type') ===       'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
  error.insertAfter(element.parent());
      } else {
  error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
  });

  $("#paymentInformation").validate({
    rules: {
      'booktype': {
        valueNotEquals: ""
      },
      'firstname': {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 200
      },
      'lastname': {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 200
      },
      'id3': {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 100,
  booknameExists: false

      }
    },
    messages: {
'booktype': {
  valueNotEquals: "Select a book type.",
},
'firstname': {
  required: "Enter your First Name.",
  maxlength: "Your First Name cannot exceed 200 characters"
},
'lastname': {
  required: "Enter your Last Name.",
  maxlength: "Your Last Name cannot exceed 200 characters"
},
'id3': {
  required: "Book name is required.",
  maxlength: "Book name cannot exceed 200 characters",
  booknameExists: "Book name already exists!"
}
   }
  });
```

Here is the jsfiddle of the whole thing: https://jsfiddle.net/damon_matt/fsLza6m0/21/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from official website: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Example: Specifies a contact element as required and as email address, the latter depending on a checkbox being checked for contact via email.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    contact: {
      required: true,
      email: {
        depends: function(element) {
          return $("#contactform_email").is(":checked");
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

so in your case something like this:

```
rules: {
      'booktype': {
        valueNotEquals: ""
      },
      'firstname': {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 200
      },
      'lastname': {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 200
      },
      'id3': {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 100,
        booknameExists: false

      },
      'description': {
        required: {
            depends: function(element) {
              return $("#usa").is(":checked");
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it didn't trigger the validator check upon checking the 'usa' checkbox - updated fiddle w/ your code: https://jsfiddle.net/fsLza6m0/22/

Comment: you made the changes inside the `messages` not in the `rules`, put the description rule inside of the rule object

Comment: Apologies - I updated, but it still not triggering the validation: https://jsfiddle.net/fsLza6m0/24/

Comment: @RogerDodger, your jsFiddle is working as expected.  The messages are updated during the next submit `click` event.  If you want the messages to be updated more dynamically, then you need to write a `change` handler that is attached to the checkbox.  Inside that click handler, put a `$('#paymentInformation').valid()`, which will immediately update the validation status of the form.

Comment: The 'Proceed to next step' button needs to be hidden if the checkbox/textarea validation fails Sparky. So essentially, it needs to be dynamic. I didn't quite understand your statement above - which click handler are you referring to?

Comment: `$("input").on("change", function() {
  checkForm();
});` if you want to trigger validation on every change, but this is was not the original question....

Comment: If you check the original fiddle - as soon as the drop down box is selected with the value, the rest of the fields all show error messages in red (since they're all empty therefore invalid). As user keeps filling out the input fields, the error messages go away, and once all fields are validated, the 'Proceed to next step' button is shown. Adding this additional textarea validation would also be a part of it - the only difference is that if user doesn't enter any text and does not click the 'usa' checkbox, the button shows, but as soon as either the checkbox is clicked & textarea is empty,

Comment: the button is hidden again, with the error message displayed above the textarea.

Comment: Thx Peter - it kinda works - but there are 2 issues: 1) the original behavior of the error messages being shown as soon as the dropdown value is selected is now gone - they're only triggered once user starts typing in the input fields 2) As I mentioned in my original question - the validation for textarea should be two-way: right now it checks only if textarea is not empty && checkbox is not checked; it doesn't check if checkbox is checked && textarea is empty. Also, the original validations seem to be disrupted - if all fields are valid, button is displayed, if text in 1 of the fields is

Comment: deleted, or if the dropdown value is changed to display "select book type", validator is not triggered, and the error for the dropdown is not displayed

Comment: OK I got the two-check working, but the issue with point 1) above (validator not triggering on change of dropdown) still persists